# error handling returns blank

Tags: php, error-handling

I have the following snippet from my code:

```
switch ($extention)
{
 case "gif": $src = @imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile); break;
 case "jpeg": $src = @imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);  break;
 case "png": $src = @imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile); break;
 default: $src = @imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);  break;
}

if(!$src)
 die("Error: Could not upload image code:#011");
```

The script terminates but does not return error. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been suggested temporarily remove the @ symbols to find out which imagecreatefrom... is breaking your script, once you've debugged it put them back in. Also because you've echoed foo after the imagecreatefrom... function that is breaking the process it'll never print out anyway.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:**

Okay so if you want to handle the errors yourself just using @ won't work, it'll suppress the message but not the fact that a fatal error occurred. You'll need to set up an error handler, have a look [here](http://www.php.net/set_error_handler) for information about this.

Comment: nothing thats my point. take away the @ symbol and returns 
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 31981568) (tried to allocate 13056 bytes) in /home/sites/snowyswebsolutions.co.uk/public_html/ACTfileUploader/uploader.php on line 90

i want to supress that error and return my own but it returns blank

Answer (score 1):

Where does it end? If that's your whole script, it's quite natural that you don't get any output (you're not outputting anything). Try putting `echo`-statements here and there do find the line where the script breaks.

**EDIT** after clarification in answers:

You can't catch the out-of-memory error in PHP, it is simply impossible (anything you would do would require more memory anyway). You can't even check if the memory would be available beforehand, since you cannot know how much memory a 10kb jpeg-image would require (it depends on the dimensions of the image, its color depth, etc.)

The only way I can think of handling such errors is making the operation outside of PHP (calling another script using `exec()` or doing it with imagemagick using `exec()` or similar)

Answer (score 0):

The `@`-operator suppresses errors, remove them.

Comment: I know, used for if you handle the errors yourself (bottom 2 lines)

Comment: @Phil No, but I guess you figured that out by now :) A pointer, always debug without error supression and `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "bar";
switch ($extention)
{
    case "gif": $src = @imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile); echo "foo"; break;
    case "jpeg": $src = @imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile); echo "foo"; break; // best quality
    case "png": $src = @imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile); echo "foo"; break; // no compression
    default: $src = @imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile); echo "foo"; break; // best quality
}

echo "foo";
if(!$src)
    die("Error: Could not upload image code:#011");
echo "foo foo";
```

returns only "bar"

Comment: You should edit your question next time to provide the additional information (sop people don't have to look into the answers section to get the whole question.) What happens if you remove the `@`-operator?